# "Javadoc: Missing reference" for correct Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have a class MyDestClass where I need to reference a field of MySourceClass in Javadoc, but I am getting the above warning.

MySourceClass

```
public class MySourceClass extends SomeClass<P, Q> {

    public static final String REFFERED = "REFFERED_STRING";

}
```

MyDestClass

```
public class MyDestClass extends SomeOtherClass<P, Q> {

    /**
     * Some comment.
     * @see {@link source.package.MySourceClass#REFFERED MySourceClass#REFFERED}
     */
    private BigDecimal destLocal;
}
```

Here the Javadoc as seen in eclipse is correct. It also takes me to the document of `REFFERED` but I am getting a warning.

Comment: Perhaps because your "MySourceClass" has no JavaDoc?

Comment: @Mukund Can you add the warning to your question?

Comment: @CKing the waring is only `Javadoc: Missing reference`. In eclipse, `@see` is yellow underlined.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I got the solution to this.

`@see` & `@link` cannot be used simultaneously

The syntax as given in the documentation is

> @see  package.class#member  label

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see

Comment: Please add the relevant text from linked site to your answer. After work is done, remove it. Reason: over the time links can become invalid.

Comment: @reporter I agree the answer would be better with some of the information embedded directly in it, but that link is to authoritative documentation, which makes it a valid citation, so I would not remove it.  (If it becomes stale, it can be easily updated in an edit, for example by changing 7 to 8 and changing the anchor.)